# Unit testing .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, unit-testing, asp.net-core

im trying to write a unit test where i want to use my MockRepository for my products and filter the products by Category Id. However i am fairly new to all of this and dont really know how i can do this.

This is my MockRepo for the producuts:

```
public class MockProductRepository : IProductsRepository
    {
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository = new MockCategoryRepository();



        public IEnumerable<Products> AllProducts =>
            new List<Products>
            {
                new Products {ProductId = 1, ProductName="Ek Stol", ProductPrice=150, ProductDescription="En fin stol", Category = _categoryRepository.AllCategories.ToList()[0],ImageUrl="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/19/14/39/antique-2079936_960_720.jpg", ImageThumbnailUrl="https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/strawberrypiesmall.jpg"},
                new Products {ProductId = 2, ProductName="Bord!", ProductPrice=250, ProductDescription="Ett fint vardagsbrod.", Category = _categoryRepository.AllCategories.ToList()[1],ImageUrl="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/07/20/11/dinner-table-663435_960_720.jpg", ImageThumbnailUrl="https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/cheesecakesmall.jpg"},
                new Products {ProductId = 3, ProductName="skål", ProductPrice=350, ProductDescription="Grym frukost skål!", Category = _categoryRepository.AllCategories.ToList()[0],ImageUrl="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/22/12/06/sunflower-seeds-1272736_960_720.jpg", ImageThumbnailUrl="https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/rhubarbpiesmall.jpg"},
                new Products {ProductId = 4, ProductName="Lådbil", ProductPrice=450,  ProductDescription="Snabbaste kärran i stan!", Category = _categoryRepository.AllCategories.ToList()[2],ImageUrl="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/23/08/04/soapbox-3492256_960_720.jpg", ImageThumbnailUrl="https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/pumpkinpiesmall.jpg"}
            };



        public Products GetProductById(int ProductId)
        {
            return AllProducts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == ProductId);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MockCategory repo:

```
namespace uppfinnaren_MarcusR91.Models
{
    public class MockCategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Category> AllCategories =>
            new List<Category>
        {
            new Category { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Stolar", Description = "Alla stolar!"},
            new Category { CategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "Bord", Description = "Alla bord!"},
            new Category { CategoryId = 3, CategoryName = "Lådbilar", Description = "Snabbaste lådbilarna i stan!"} 
        };
    }
}
```

And what i want to do is write a unit test where i check if i can filter the products by categoryId.
This is what i have written so far in my unit tets:

```
namespace TestProjectUppfinnaren
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestFilteringProductsByCategory()
        {
            var mockData = new MockProductRepository();
            
            var products =  mockData.AllProducts.Where(x => x.CategoryId == 2);
 
        } 
    }
}
```

I need some sort of assert i believe that will make sure that the products and the categoryId im trying to filter should be the same. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: One of the important things of unit testing is to identify the System Under Test (SUT). That's the component that you're actually trying to verify the behavior of.  In this case, the thing that you're trying to verify the behavior of is your MockProductRepository. However, if you think about it, that doesn't make sense to do. The MockProductRepository is only there to help assist you in testing, so your real app code doesn't have to talk to a database during a unit test. The System Under Test *should* be the code that depends on IProductsRepository.

Comment: That might be a controller action method, or if you've got a business logic layer, it might be some method in there. Carefully identifying the component of your application that you want to test, and then mocking the dependencies of that component, will be key to writing a successful unit test.

Comment: Your assert would be something along the lines of "this actually retrieved the record I expected it to retrieve," or "This actually modified the field I expected to be modified."  In general, I'm not a fan of tests like these, because they don't involve any non-trivial logic.  They're great for textbooks, but in practice I think I would favor some sort of integration/smoke test for unremarkable repository operations.

Comment: Also, part of the point of unit testing is to identify deficiencies in your design.  If the code is difficult to mock/test, sometimes the right response is to rewrite the code so that it is no longer difficult to mock/test.